# Detectar configuração de proxy no webrequest

Tags: c#, proxy, webrequest

Boa tarde meus caros, preciso realizar uma requisição para uma api que fica em um domínio externo a rede local, realizo isto através de uma webrequest que foi criada deste maneira:

```
WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("urldestino");
```

Porém, a rede possui um proxy, que barrava minhas solicitações informando que a autenticação do proxy era necessária. Para testar o funcionamento, consegui realizar a requisição setando o proxy manualmente da seguinte maneira:

```
WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy();
myProxy = (WebProxy)WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
myProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("meuusuario", "minhasenha", "meudominio");
myWebRequest.Proxy = myProxy;
```

Detalhe: após a execução de `"myProxy = (WebProxy)WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();"`
o myProxy.Credentials ficou null, por isto setei manualmente.

Desta maneira, a request passa pelo proxy, porém, fui orientado a obter a sessão do proxy já autenticada pelo windows, da mesma maneira que os browsers e o postman faz, no postman por exemplo eu realizo a requisição sem a necessidade de informar os dados do proxy e ele não me retorna um proxy authentication is required.

Existe alguma maneira, de eu obter a sessão do proxy autenticada, sem que precise passar manualmente a matrícula e senha dos usuários logados?

Desde já muito lhes agradeço.

Comment: O proxy está configurado no WIndows e está como padrão?

Comment: Acredito que sim, está setado no browser para "usar script de configuração automática" e abaixo está setado o endereço dele.

Comment: Então não precisa de código nenhum, o padrão do WebRequest é usar o proxy configurado no SO. Não vou colocar como resposta porque não tenho como testar agora, mas testa aí e deixa um feedback nos comentários =D

Comment: Ele não está obtendo automático, acredito que ele obteria no myProxy = (WebProxy)WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy(); porém o myproxy não recebe as credenciais já configuradas, e ao nao passar as credenciais recebi um "{"The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required."}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar de passar as credenciais manualmente você pode obter as credenciais da seguinte maneira:

```
WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy();
myProxy = (WebProxy)WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
myProxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
myWebRequest.Proxy = myProxy;
```

Com o `System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;`  ele retornará as credenciais já setadas no IE por default, logo abaixo voce seta ao webrequest.proxy as credenciais.

Comment: Funcionou da forma como precisava, autenticou no proxy com sucesso obtendo as credenciais sem precisar passar os dados do usuário. Muito obrigado.